# Understanding Block and Definition

Tags: scoping, variable-definitions

The code

```
Block[{f}, f := test; Definition[f]]
```

Outputs `Null`. Why? I would have expected it to output the definition of `f`, like `f := test; Definition[f]` does.

---

Does it have to do with Definition being an output form. If so how can I get a function that does the exact same thing but that really evaluates to the value shown as output?

Comment: it is because `Definition` and similar functions `Print` the definitions associated to the symbol, instead of giving them as output. Are you asking for a function that takes a symbol as input and gives the definitions as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because `Definition` does not evaluate.

It is a wrapper which is formatted the way you are familiar with.

```
f:="test"

FullForm @ Definition[f]
```

> ```
> Definition[f]
> ```

So during evaluation definitions are not (meant to be) collected, `Block` returns `Definition[f]` and later it is formatted to `Null` as our `Block` does not  exist anymore.

`Print` workaround works because it forces print cell creation, so formatting and  typesetting too, before `Block` is done. So definitions can be collected.

Another way to force formatting stage:

```
Block[{f}, f := test; ToString[Definition[f], InputForm]]
```

it is better than `Print` because the latter can be sent to the console, depending on your settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to get a cell that prints the definition of `f` while `Block`ed, you can use `Print` since `Print` will create the cell while `f` is still `Block`ed:

```
Block[{f}, f := test; Print[Definition[f]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking for, but here is a simple (and naive, it will probably not work on more complicated cases) way to convert the output of `DownValues` to a format similar to the output of `Definition`:

```
definitions[symb_Symbol] := DownValues @ symb /. {
    Verbatim[RuleDelayed][a_, b_] :> Hold[SetDelayed[a, b]]
    } /. Verbatim[HoldPattern][args__] :> args
```

for example:

```
foo[x_] := x + 2;
foo[x_List] := x + 3
foo[x_, y_] := x + y
definitions @ foo
```

produces

```
{Hold[foo[x_List] := x + 3], Hold[foo[x_] := x + 2], Hold[foo[x_, y_] := x + y]}
```

To also remove the `Hold` from the output you can use this other version:

```
definitions[symb_Symbol] := DownValues @ symb /. {
     Verbatim[RuleDelayed][a_, b_] :> Hold[SetDelayed[a, b]]
  } /. Verbatim[HoldPattern][args__] :> args /. {
     Hold[args__] :> Defer[args]
  }
```

Replacing `DownValues` with `Definitions` from `GeneralUtilities` should moreover generalise the function to also capture `UpValues`, `OwnValues` etc.